# PubNub: What is the right way to log all published message to my db

Tags: pubnub

What is the right way to log every published message and save it to my server db.

There are two options which I can think of:

1. Use PubNub function *After Publish event* and forward the message to a dedicated logger channel. the server will subscribe to the channel and save the arrived messages to db. *Here rise another question: when I forward the message to another channel in the PubNub function will it also trigger the PubNub function?*
2. use PubNub XHR request/response function and call to a rest API on my server with the published message and save it to db

**What is the best practice concerning performance and cost?**

Comment: Hi @tomn we are in process to answering your question.  Check back soon!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Save PubNub Messages to your Private Database

We wrote an article that talks about the [right way to log JSON Messages to a Private Database](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/the-right-way-to-log-all-messages-to-a-private-database/).

> While many approaches exist.  One is best.  Using [PubNub Functions](https://www.pubnub.com/products/functions/). You will **asynchronously** save messages reliably to your Database.  Using an **OnAfter Publish** Event.  Your database needs to be accessible via a secured HTTPS endpoint.

PubNub does not index your messages using [FTS Indexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full-text_search); at time of writing.  You may want Full Text Search Indexing using your database or use an API provider like https://www.algolia.com/ for full text searching.

Data is valuable. AI and ML allows you to create insight from your data using [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/). You may want to run data analysis for the message content.  Using [EMR / Hadoop](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/) or other big data analysis software.

You will use [PubNub Functions](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/blocks/function) to save your message asynchronously into your database system easily by following these steps.

[image: PubNub Save Message to Database]

To get started is easy. Assuming you already have a stream of messages being published to a PubNub data channel.  Follow these easy steps. Successfully you will create a **realtime** function that is triggered every Publish event.

1. Collect a list of channel(s).  You may be interested in **ALL** channels **`*`**.
2. In your [Account Dashboard](https://admin.pubnub.com/) find **your app**, then click **Functions**.
3. Create a new Module for your specified API key set.
4. Create a new **OnAfter** event handler on **`*`** channel.
5. Use the following example code to save, asynchronously, your messages to your database.
6. Make sure to modify the URL/Parameters to fit your needs.

#### Asynchronous HTTPS Save Message Function

```js
// Request Handler
export default request => { 
    return save(request).then( () => request.ok() );
}

// Async Logging/Save of JSON Messages
function save( data, retry=3 ) {
    const xhr  = require('xhr');
    const post = { method : "POST", body : request.message };
    const url  = "https://my.company.com/save"; // <-- CHANGE URL HERE

    // save message asynchronously
    return xhr.fetch( url, post ).then( serverResponse => {
        // Save Success! 
    }).catch( err => {
        // Retry
        if (retry > 0) save( data, --retry );
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, is their any way to retry to save the message in
 catch( err => {
        // Save Failed! handle err
  });

Or ultimately, how can I apply recurrsion to Pubnub function? 
The actual functionality I need is that function tries to save the message again if any error occurs.

Comment: Each function has an execution timeout at `10s`.  If a failure occurs today, it's best practice to relay the failure back to the client with an error response.  The client can try again. 

You can also add in a few server-side retries.  Create a function that saves your result.  Then use that function in a retry loop until it succeeds or you hit the retry quota.

Comment: Thankyou so much :)