# Is it possible to export pubnub chat messages to a postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, pubnub

I am prototyping a mobile app and i want to make it quickly. For that purpose, i am using `pubnub chat engine`.

However, i plan to migrate to a postgresql database after the end of the beta test. But i don't want to lose the existing data already stored in pubnub. Are there some possibilities to export my chat data to my own  postgreSQL database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Export PubNub Chat Messages to your PostgeSQL Database

> While many approaches exist.  One is best.  Using [PubNub Functions](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/the-right-way-to-log-all-messages-to-a-private-database/). You will **asynchronously** save messages reliably to your Database.  Using an **OnAfter Publish** Event.  Your database needs to be accessible via a secured HTTPS endpoint.

Stackoverflow Answer: [PubNub: What is the right way to log all published message to my db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48665018/pubnub-what-is-the-right-way-to-log-all-published-message-to-my-db/48673346#48673346) - You will want to [Save your JSON Messages to a Private Database](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/the-right-way-to-log-all-messages-to-a-private-database/) using the method described in the links.  Example code referenced below in this post.

```
export default request => { 
    const xhr  = require('xhr');
    const post = { method : "POST", body : request.message };
    const url  = "https://my.company.com/save";

    // save message asynchronously
    xhr.fetch( url, post ).then( serverResponse => {
        // DB Save Success! 
    }).catch( err => {
        // DB Save Failed! handle err
    });
    return request.ok();
}
```

Comment: what if this was not set up and now, you want to export all existing messages to postgres for instance, is their an effective approach for this other than https://www.pubnub.com/docs/chat/sdks/messages/message-history which I recently came across